# How to insert/update data in 2 oracle database which are in Active/Active configuration and bi-directional replication

Tags: database-replication

Background:
There are 2 oracle database which are in Active/Active configuration and setup for bi-directional replication to keep both in sync all the time.

Goal - Replication latency to be less than 3 mins

Issue- There is more than  4 hours of replication latency due to  batch jobs having commit rate of 10K transactions per second. these batch is making (insert/update) on primary DB & it gets replicated to other DB.

Problem- 1. even after tuning commit rate to 1K, latency is still more than 1 hour. 
2. If batch is set to run on both site and no replication at all then, two different set of primary keys for same records with exists in 2 DB.

Is there different way to run these batch job on these 2 DB with out replication but ensuing data is in sync?

Comment: What's your hardware?  What's your OS?  Also, your question is likely to be moved to another site as stackoverflow is for programming, and you haven't really asked a *programming* question.